# How can I link the changing of an angular element in an input to an output field?

Tags: angularjs

I tried the following example from the O'Reily book that just came out:

```
<form ng-controller="StartUpController">
Starting: <input ng-change="computeNeeded()"
ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
</form>

function StartUpController($scope) {
$scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
$scope.computeNeeded = function() {
$scope.needed = $scope.startingEstimate * 10;
};
}
```

[plunk](http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/pHiPhS?p=preview)

The code does not seem to work and I am not sure why. Can anyone see what is wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have a few problems here.

**`$scope.startingEstimate` does not exist**

`startingEstimate` belongs instead to `$scope.funding`. To access it, you would write `$scope.funding.startingEstimate`. You might want to read this article for information about how objects work in JavaScript, if you are unfamiliar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

**`funding.needed` does not exist**

You'll need to use `{{needed}}`, because you're assigning `$scope.needed`, not `$scope.funding.needed`.

Your code could then look something like this and work:

```
<form ng-controller="StartUpController">
   Starting: <input ng-change="computeNeeded()"
   ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
   Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
</form>

function StartUpController($scope) {
   $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
   $scope.computeNeeded = function() {
      $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
   };
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Actually the book I am learning from has these problems. Seems like the author didn't check what he was writing :-( Book just came out but there are going to be a lot of people confused if they try to learn from it. Thanks very much.

Comment: That doesn't sound good at all. Hopefully future examples weren't ignored by the proofreaders as much as this one.